# Show convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a complex sequence, assume that $\{b_{2n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{b_{2n-1}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ both converges towards $b \in \mathbb{C} $. Show that $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ must also converge towards $b$. 
It's quite easy to see that this is true, however I don't know how to show it rigorously.

Whould it be enough to argue that the union of the positive odd and even numbers are the natural numbers, and therefore it must be true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $n \geq N$?

Comment: Where does this N come from? You only have to argue for the existence such N.

Comment: Can you write down precisely what it means for $\{b_{2n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{b_{2n-1}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to converge? That might help.

Comment: The $N$ is chosen such that $|b_{2n} - b|< \epsilon$ when $n\geq N$

Comment: I just dont know how to combine the subsequences

Comment: For me the argument of union is sufficient, I don't see the need to do more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an epsilon, and taking a maximum of the two $N$'s guaranteed to exist for the two sequences, we have for any $2n-1\geq k=\max\{ N_1,N_2\}$, 
$$
|b_{2n}-b|<\epsilon/2\\
|b-b_{2n-1}|<\epsilon/2
$$
add those together, use the triangle inequality, and recall the Cauchy criterion.

Comment: That leaves me with $|b_{2n}-b_{2n-1}| < \epsilon $ which isnt sufficient to show its a Cauchy sequence

Comment: it certainly is. In fact it is stronger. To be cauchy, you are only required to find me a term somewhere further down the sequence which is arbitrarily close. Here that term is the next one in the sequence.

Comment: For it to be Cauchy it should be true for all m, n larger than N, not just be true for successive terms. But maybe im missing something ?

Comment: yes, what i have written is true for *any* $2n-1\geq k$

Comment: Oh, yes sorry, my bad. Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. We need to prove that there exists $N$ such that $|b_n - b| < \varepsilon$ for $n > N$. But for the subsequences $\{b_{2n}\}$ and $\{b_{2n-1}\}$ there exist such $N_1$ and $N_2$. So $N = max(N_1, N_2)$.

Comment: You have to be careful with $N_1$ and $N_2$. Do you mean for all $n >N_1$, $|b_{2n}-b|<\epsilon$? If so, your $N$ is not quite right.

Comment: It should be $N = 2 \cdot max(N_1, N_2)$ right?